# Get date of next nearest weekday from today

Tags: php, date, weekday

I need to get date of next nearest weekday from today.( For ex : I will give three random weekdays like Sunday, Monday, Saturday. From this list I need to get next nearest weekday from today ( Thursday ) output is should be Saturday. Here after I want to get date of coming Saturday.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Hint: `java.time.LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay()  )`

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l', strtotime('today')+2*24*60*60);
```

Comment: Days are not always 24-hours long.

Answer (score 0):

Can not understand your question clearly.. 
I suggest a solution based on my understanding...
You should create a hash that map a weekday with a number,
example:

```
{
    Sun => 0,
    Mon => 1,
    ...
    Sat => 6
}
```

Then get the MIN absolute value of current day with the list of your random weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
echo nearestWeekend( '26-12-2015' );

function nearestWeekend( $date ){
    $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date . '+1 day'));
    while( !preg_match('/Sunday|Saturday/i' , date('l', strtotime($date)) ) ){
        $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date . '+1 day'));
    }
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
}
```